# enable disable inputs text with its corresponding checkbox jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having several rows, where each row has a checkbox, a label, and an input text

How can I enable/disable the checkbox's neighbour input text when the check box is selected, using jquery. By this I mean to just enable/disable the input that is on same row with checkbox

I have:

```
<form>
    <p>         
        <input id="chk1" type="checkbox">
  <label >text 1 </label>
  <input id="input1" type="text">
    </p>
    <p>
      <input id="chk2" type="checkbox">
  <label >text 2 </label>
  <input id="input2" type="text">
    </p>
<p>
      <input id="chk3" type="checkbox">
  <label >text 3 </label>
  <input id="input3" type="text">
    </p>
</form>
```

and do not know how to do this

```
$(':checkbox').change(function(){
   $('input:text').?find?.prop("disabled", !$(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

[here is fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DaS39/1756/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe like this:

```js
$(':checkbox').change(function(){
   var this_nr=$(this).attr('id').substr(-1);
   $('#input'+this_nr).prop('disabled', !$(this).is(':checked'));
});
$(':checkbox').change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <p>
        <input id="chk1" type="checkbox">
  <label >text 1 </label>
  <input id="input1" type="text">
    </p>
    <p>
      <input id="chk2" type="checkbox">
  <label >text 2 </label>
  <input id="input2" type="text">
    </p>
<p>
      <input id="chk3" type="checkbox">
  <label >text 3 </label>
  <input id="input3" type="text">
    </p>
</form>
```

or like this:

```js
$(':checkbox').change(function(){
   $('input:text').eq($(':checkbox').index(this)).prop("disabled", !$(this).is(':checked'));
});
$(':checkbox').change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <p>
        <input id="chk1" type="checkbox">
  <label >text 1 </label>
  <input id="input1" type="text">
    </p>
    <p>
      <input id="chk2" type="checkbox">
  <label >text 2 </label>
  <input id="input2" type="text">
    </p>
<p>
      <input id="chk3" type="checkbox">
  <label >text 3 </label>
  <input id="input3" type="text">
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: liked the idea, however Would be better to use `var this_nr=$(this).attr('id').replace(/\D/g,'');`

Comment: @cMinor I have same issue but my input fields are randomly generated from array, can you please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57849991/enable-disable-generated-input-by-array-with-relevant-checkbox-jquery

Answer (score 3):

I would use event delegation on the form, in the handler using [nextAll](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) to find the next text box.

```js
// disable all the text fields
$('#myform :text').each(function () {
  $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});

$('#myform').on('change', ':checkbox', function (evt) {
  let textbox = $(this).nextAll(':text');
  textbox.prop('disabled', (i, val) => !val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <p>         
    <input id="chk1" type="checkbox">
    <label for="chk1">text 1 </label>
    <input id="input1" type="text">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input id="chk2" type="checkbox">
    <label for="chk2">text 2 </label>
    <input id="input2" type="text">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input id="chk3" type="checkbox">
    <label for="chk3">text 3 </label>
    <input id="input3" type="text">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="tos">I agree to the Terms of Service</label><input id="tos" type="checkbox"><br>
    <label for="comment">Comments </label><input id="comment" type="text" value="This will toggle when you check the TOS">
  </p>
</form>
```

This works if your entire form is in this checkbox followed by textbox form; it will break if you have any other checkboxes that don't control a textbox or textboxes that shouldn't be disabled. To be more flexible, I would add a class to the items I wanted to have this behavior:

```js
// disable all the text fields
$('#myform :text.toggle-input').each(function () {
  $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});

$('#myform').on('change', ':checkbox.toggle-input', function (evt) {
  let textbox = $(this).nextAll(':text.toggle-input');
  textbox.prop('disabled', (i, val) => !val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <p>         
    <input id="chk1" class="toggle-input" type="checkbox">
    <label for="chk1">text 1 </label>
    <input id="input1" class="toggle-input" type="text">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input id="chk2" class="toggle-input" type="checkbox">
    <label for="chk2">text 2 </label>
    <input id="input2" class="toggle-input" type="text">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input id="chk3" class="toggle-input" type="checkbox">
    <label for="chk3">text 3 </label>
    <input id="input3" class="toggle-input" type="text">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="tos">I agree to the Terms of Service</label><input id="tos" type="checkbox"><br>
    <label for="comment">Comments </label><input id="comment" type="text" value="This won't toggle when you check the TOS">
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the jQuery [`siblings`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) function to retrieve the neighboring textbox and enable/disable it based on the `.checked` property. I've called `.change()` at the end to set the initial state of the textboxes.

```js
$(":checkbox")
  .change(function() {
    $(this)
      .siblings("input[type='text']")
      .prop("disabled", !this.checked);
  }).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <p>
    <input id="chk1" type="checkbox">
    <label>text 1 </label>
    <input id="input1" type="text">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input id="chk2" type="checkbox">
    <label>text 2 </label>
    <input id="input2" type="text">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input id="chk3" type="checkbox">
    <label>text 3 </label>
    <input id="input3" type="text">
  </p>
</form>
```